# jQuery mobile has delay

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am building wordpress website that has some jQuery animations. For example, when I scroll menu will hide when I scroll down and show when I scroll up.

Also, I have some toggleClass for showing and hiding some grid with images. On desktop everything works smoothly and without issues, but on mobile there are huge delays for hiding and showing menu, and toggleClass doesn't work sometimes.

Although everything works when I resize browser on desktop and hit smaller resolutions, but on mobile doesn't. I'm using Samsung A3 2016, and it's not slow phone.

Does any one have solution?

This is the code I am using. Am I perhaps using too much code?

```
jQuery('.custom-search i').click(function() {
  jQuery('.search-query').toggleClass('showsearch');
});

jQuery('a.popup-open').click(function() {
  jQuery('.popup-submit').css('display', 'block');
});

jQuery('.popup-close').click(function() {
  jQuery('.popup-submit').css('display', 'none');
});

jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
  var h = jQuery(".x-navbar").height();
  var t1 = jQuery(".hide-me").offset().top;
  if ((jQuery(this).scrollTop() + h) >= t1) {
    jQuery('.hidden-menu').css({
      "display": "block"
    });
    jQuery('.x-navbar-wrap').css({
      "background-color": "#eaeaea"
    });
    jQuery('.x-brand.img').css({
      "visibility": "hidden"
    });
    jQuery('.x-navbar .desktop .x-nav > li > a > span').css({
      "color": "#111"
    });
    jQuery('.custom-search i').css({
      "color": "#111"
    });
    jQuery('.home .x-navbar .places-menu').css({
      "color": "#111"
    });


  } else {
    jQuery('.hidden-menu').css({
      "display": "none"
    });
    jQuery('.x-navbar-wrap').css({
      "background-color": "transparent"
    });
    jQuery('.x-brand.img').css({
      "visibility": "visible"
    });
    jQuery('.x-navbar .desktop .x-nav > li > a > span').css({
      "color": "#fff"
    });
    jQuery('.custom-search i').css({
      "color": "#fff"
    });
    jQuery('.home .x-navbar .places-menu').css({
      "color": "#fff"
    });
  }
});

jQuery('.places-map').click(function() {
  jQuery('.map-container').toggleClass('show-container');
  jQuery('.close-map').css('display', 'block');
});

jQuery('.close-map').click(function() {
  jQuery('.map-container').toggleClass('show-container');
  jQuery('.close-map').css('display', 'none');
});

jQuery('.places-menu').click(function() {
  jQuery('.places-grid').toggleClass('show-grid', '1000');
  jQuery('.img-rotate').toggleClass('rotate');
});

jQuery('.box').click(function() {
  jQuery('.places-grid').toggleClass('show-grid', '1000');
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  jQuery('.place-region a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(document).off("scroll");

    jQuery('.place-region a').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash;
    $target = jQuery(target);
    jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
    }, 500, 'swing', function() {
      window.location.hash = target;
      jQuery(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
  });
});

function onScroll(event) {
  var scrollPosition = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
  jQuery('.place-region a').each(function() {
    var currentLink = jQuery(this);
    var refElement = jQuery(currentLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
      jQuery('.place-region a').removeClass("active");
      currentLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
      currentLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}

// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = jQuery('.x-navbar-wrap').outerHeight();

jQuery(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

  // Make sure they scroll more than delta
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

  // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
  // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
    // Scroll Down
    jQuery('.x-navbar-wrap').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    jQuery('.hidden-menu').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    jQuery('.place-bar').removeClass('nav-down-place').addClass('nav-up-place');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up
    if (st + jQuery(window).height() < jQuery(document).height()) {
      jQuery('.x-navbar-wrap').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
      jQuery('.hidden-menu').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
      jQuery('.place-bar').removeClass('nav-up-place').addClass('nav-down-place');
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added touchstart along with click action and everything works perfectly on mobile phones.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.home .box').on('click', function() {
        jQuery('.places-grid').removeClass('show-grid' , '1000');
    });
});
```

And I have added this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.home .box').on('touchstart click', function() {
        jQuery('.places-grid').removeClass('show-grid' , '1000');
    });
});
```